How to create a struct to hold all variants of an enum
I'm working on a program which uses different instructions sets depending on which option is selected, at the minute I'm using the choose_instruction_set function to choose which option is selected.
enum PrintFileLanguage {
    PJL,
    PCL,
    PCL6,
    PS,
}

enum SelectedOption {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
struct Instructions;


#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
struct AllOptionInstructions {
    a: Instructions,
    b: Instructions,
    c: Instructions,
}

fn choose_instruction_set(option: SelectedOption, all_options: AllOptionInstructions) -> Instructions {
    match option {
        SelectedOption::A => all_options.a,
        SelectedOption::B => all_options.b,
        SelectedOption::C => all_options.c,
    }
}

However, I'd much rather use the enum variants as the field names of the structs so that they can be matched directly i.e. somehting like
fn test(opt: SelectedOption) -> Instructions {
    Instructions = AllOptionInstructions::opt
}

Is there a way to do this?

Perhaps what you need is not a struct but enum_map?

Sounds like Instructions might be a Trait, and your options can be it's implementations.

Note: I think the code you originally posted is fine. I'd personally stick with that because of the exhaustive nature of match.

A simple HashMap would do.
struct AllOptionInstructions {
    instructions: HashMap<SelectedOption, Instructions>,
}

Initialize it with all the options:
fn new() -> Self {
    AllOptionInstructions {
        instructions: HashMap::from([
            (SelectedOption::A, Instructions{}),
            (SelectedOption::B, Instructions{}),
            (SelectedOption::C, Instructions{}),
        ]),
    }
}

And just use a lookup to get the values by enum key.
fn choose_instruction_set(&self, option: SelectedOption) -> Option<&Instructions> {
    self.instructions.get(&option)
}

Full example on Playground.
